# Code for mouse click

Tags: c#, click, mouse

I'm trying to make a click at desktop through code, so I did that:

```
    public static void MouseLeftClick(Point pos)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = pos;
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN, pos.X, pos.Y, 0, 0);
        mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, pos.X, pos.Y, 0, 0);
    }
```

I realize that it only works if I add the System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = pos;
Why? mouse_event x,y parameters are useless?

Comment: What does `mouse_event` look like?

Comment: some people just love to vote down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you read the [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646260%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) of the `mouse_event` function?

If for instance only `RIGHTDOWN` is used, X and Y parameters don't represent the coordinates where the mouse is set..

Here's how you could deal with `mouse`_event:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern void mouse_event(MouseEventFlags dwFlags, uint dx, uint dy, uint dwData, UIntPtr dwExtraInfo);

...

// Converts into pixels
uint x = (uint)(pos.X * 65535 / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width);
uint y = (uint)(pos.Y * 65535 / Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);

// Moves the mouse (absolute)
mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.MOVE | MouseEventFlags.ABSOLUTE, x, y, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);

// Now button down
mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.RIGHTDOWN, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
mouse_event(MouseEventFlags.RIGHTUP, 0, 0, 0, UIntPtr.Zero);
```

Of course, setting the cursor position is much more simple than using `mouse_event` to tell that your mouse has moved.

Btw, this function has been superseded. Use [`SendInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646310%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead.